# Google calendar crashed when I am trying to editing event

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I have strange issue, I don't know how to resolve this. I have tested many things but dont know what the problem.

Ok I have create simple program to Insert event into google calendar device this will inserted into google calendar successfully.

When I am trying to editing from google calendar or click on edit menu google calendar will be crashed. I have testing in many devices the problem was same for all the device calendar.

here is my code

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Uri EVENTS_URI = null;

        EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        values.put("calendar_id", 1);
        values.put("title", "event.eventName");
        values.put("allDay", 0);
        values.put("dtstart", time); 
        values.put("dtend", time + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2);
        values.put("description", "description");
        values.put("visibility", 0);
        values.put("transparency", 0);
        values.put("hasAttendeeData", 0);
        values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        values.put("eventLocation", "location");
        cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
```

I am not able to detecting or reason that why this happen in my inserted event only

Comment: Pratik, logcat output always helpful to idetify issue.

Comment: Sorry paresh I am not able to get Google calendar log output I am getting error in Google calendar not in my application

Comment: For which SDKs are you testing on?

Comment: Your logcat will still print out why it crashes even though it isn't your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysis for inserting event and searching the logcat for calendar I have found that my calendar was force close when I am trying to edit the event which was inserted from my application.

The reason is I have not set the TimeZone field value for my event and in calendar it will get as null pointer at editing time that's why it gone to force close

I have also search for logcat application for android I found this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result

to detect all the log its very useful to me from that log I know that TimeZone filled value null and calendar application gone to crashed.

so I just add this filled value at inserting time and it's work perfectly.

for ICS

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

below ICS

```
values.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd consider doing it with intents you could do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID) {
    // all SDK below ice cream sandwich
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("description", description);
    intent.putExtra("eventLocation", location);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", isAllDay);

//  intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
} else {
    // ice cream sandwich and above
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY , isAllDay);
    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);

//  intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10") 
}
try {
    context.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
} catch(Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```